# Ampscript Retrieve and Update Salesforce Integer Field

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

The following code for SFMC retrieves and updates the value of a an integer field in our regular SF (CRM) client. The integer field starts at 0. I am trying to increase the integer value by 1 each time the code is executed. The issue I am seeing is that it updates the value of the field by 4 each time. How can I rework this code so that it updates the number only by 1 each time?

```
%%[
VAR @SOOBJECT, @UPDATE, @SOCOUNTER, @SINGLE, @CURRENT, @SOOBJECTROW,
SET @SINGLE = 1
SET @SOOBJECT= RetrieveSalesforceObjects('PBSI__PBSI_Sales_Order__c', 'Order_Confirmation__c', 'Id', '=', LongSFID([Sales Order: ID]))
SET @SOOBJECTROW = Row(@SOOBJECT,1)
SET @SOCOUNTER = FormatNumber(FIELD(@SOOBJECTROW,"Order_Confirmation__c"),"N")
SET @UPDATE = Add(@SOCOUNTER,@SINGLE)
SET @CURRENT = UpdateSingleSalesforceObject('PBSI__PBSI_Sales_Order__c',LongSFID([Sales Order: ID]),'Order_Confirmation__c',@UPDATE)
]%%
```

Comment: How and where is the code executed?

Comment: At send time, executed in the email. Should I be executing as a script activity?

Answer (score 1):

You should probably only execute your code for the SEND [**_MessageContext**](http://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/content/personalization_strings/strings/):

```
%%[

if _messagecontext == "SEND" then

    VAR @SOOBJECT, @UPDATE, @SOCOUNTER, @SINGLE, @CURRENT, @SOOBJECTROW    

    SET @SINGLE = 1
    SET @SOOBJECT= RetrieveSalesforceObjects('PBSI__PBSI_Sales_Order__c', 'Order_Confirmation__c', 'Id', '=', LongSFID([Sales Order: ID]))
    SET @SOOBJECTROW = Row(@SOOBJECT,1)
    SET @SOCOUNTER = FormatNumber(FIELD(@SOOBJECTROW,"Order_Confirmation__c"),"N")
    SET @UPDATE = Add(@SOCOUNTER,@SINGLE)
    SET @CURRENT = UpdateSingleSalesforceObject('PBSI__PBSI_Sales_Order__c',LongSFID([Sales Order: ID]),'Order_Confirmation__c',@UPDATE)

endif

]%%
```

Here are the possible `_MessageContext` values:

- **SEND** - Display the rendered final message for sending to subscriber
- **PREVIEW** - Display the send preview options available within editor
- **VAWP** - Display content
- **VIEWSENT** - Display the non-subscriber link to preview content
- **FTAF** - Display the rendered Forward To a Friend message
- **LANDINGPAGE** - Display a landing page or microsite
- **VALIDATION** - Display information corresponding to the validate option in Marketing Cloud
- **LINKRESOLUTION** - Display resolved dynamic script at click time
- **SMS** - Display SMS message content
- **SOCIAL** - Display Social Forward content
- **SITE** - Display CloudPage content

Comment: Thank you for this! I implemented this conditional, and I am avoiding triggering the integer update during the content preview/testing. However, after sending, it is still updates the integer directly to 4. So obviously there is some kind of feedback loop as the code is currently constructed. Just not sure where.

Comment: What happens when add `outputline(concat("<br>SOCOUNTER: ",@SOCOUNTER))` after your `SET @SOCOUNTER` line?

Comment: @SOCOUNTER is coming back as 4 from the outputline function. I put that code block into a code snippet div wrapper, (thinking maybe the code was being executed in multiple contexts, including rendering of auto-links), but still no luck.

Comment: Please update your question with the outputline and the output you're seeing when you do an email send.  If you are saying that `Order_Confirmation__c` has a value of 4 and it's displayed 4 times, then I'm confused about what you're totaling.

Comment: No, sorry, this is the output line that displays in the email: SOCOUNTER: 4.00

Comment: Looks like it's working fine then.  If there's only one output line, then it's only evaluating your block once.

Comment: Yea, the output is working fine, but the counter should correctly be at 1 the first time, not 4. Should I be looking at ClaimRow or InsertDE functions? It seems from the documentation that they only work with Data extenstions, but insert DE is essentially exactly what I am trying to do, only in the salesforce org, not the MC org.

Comment: Is this the field that holds the counter in your SF object: `Order_Confirmation__c`?  I'm guessing that it's that this line is not referencing the correct field: `SET @SOCOUNTER = FormatNumber(FIELD(@SOOBJECTROW,"Order_Confirmation__c"),"N")`

Comment: Yes, that is the field which holds the counter: "Order_Confirmation__c". The correct field seems to be being referenced, it just updates it from 1 to 2 to 3 to 4 the first time the code is run (rather than just 1). When I output the variable so it is visible during the preview, I can actualy see the number ("SOCOUNTER: XX") changing upwards The formatnumber function hasn't seemed to affect anything, same problem happens with just the field function.